# Adding coordinates of clicks with glut to a linked list of vectors

Tags: c, opengl, linked-list, glut, opengl-compat

I want to create a linked list of vectors and with the help of GLUT library get the positions of the clicks and append them to the linked list.

These are the structs i wrote.

```
typedef struct vector{int x;int y;}Vector;
typedef struct VectorList{Vector X; struct VectorList*next; }node_v;
```

I globally defined a P vector and linked list of vectors prev.

```
Vector P;
node_v * prev=NULL;
```

Inside the mouse callback function _mouse_CB everytime left mouse button is clicked, i want to update the P vector with the current x and y values and append them to the linked list.

This is that part of the code.

```
static void _mouse_CB(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        switch(button)
        {
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON :
            px=x;py=y;
            P.x=x;
            P.y=y;
            prev=VL_new1(P);

            append(&prev,P);
            break;
```

the append function here i wrote from geeksforgeeks and added a while loop at the end to check if the values are added correctly, but i am getting overflow.

```
void append(node_v** head_ref, Vector A)
{ 
    node_v* new_node = (node_v*) malloc(sizeof(node_v)); 

    node_v *last = *head_ref;  

    new_node->X.x  = A.x; 
      new_node->X.y  = A.y; 
    new_node->next = NULL; 

    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node; 
       return; 
    }   
    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 
    last->next = new_node; 
    last = *head_ref;
    while(last){
      printf("%d %d\n", last->X.x,last->X.y);
      last = last->next;
    }
    return;     
}
```

To create a node i wrote this function

```
node_v* VL_new1(Vector A){
        node_v *new = (node_v*)malloc(sizeof(node_v));
        if(new==NULL){exit(1);}
        else{
            new->X.x  = A.x; 
            new->X.y  = A.y; 
            new->next = NULL;
        }
        return new;
}
```

Each time i run this program and click on the appeared window, on the terminal the printf inside append function outputs this

```
-732680176 -729092496
0 -1344244448
```

What changes should i make to not get overflow and successfully add the current values?

Comment: Suggest `node_v* new_node = (node_v*) malloc(sizeof(node_v));` => `node_v* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));`

Comment: Remove `prev=VL_new1(P);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 that's the function i created to allocate the node

Comment: @JoJo The new node is created in `append`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new node is created in the function `append`:

> ```c
> node_v* new_node = (node_v*) malloc(sizeof(node_v));
> ```

The instruction `prev=VL_new1(P);` generates a new list head. Every time when the code is executed, then `prev` is set and the previous content of `prev` is lost.

Remove if:

```c
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON :
    px=x;py=y;
    P.x=x;
    P.y=y;
    append(&prev,P);
```

Note, the function `VL_new1` can be called in `append`, instead:

```c
void append(node_v** head_ref, Vector A)
{ 
    node_v *last = *head_ref;
    node_v* new_node = VL_new1(A); 

    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node; 
       return; 
    }

    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 
    last->next = new_node;
}
```

Comment: i removed and compiled but i am still getting overflow

Comment: inside the append function, i added this line at the very end `printf("%d %d\n",A.x,A.y);` and clicked on the screen and it printed `-563777520 -560359568`

Comment: inside the mouse_cb it printed the correct coordinates but not inside append, i think it;s the needed outcome

Comment: Yes ,it is the `glutMouseFunc(_mouse_CB);` that i call inside the main function

Comment: i wrote `#include <stdlib.h>` only

Comment: @JoJo So please `#include <malloc.h>`