# Drawing a linestrip with opengl1 by looping through a linked list of vectors

Tags: c, opengl, linked-list, glut, opengl-compat

i have previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527670/adding-coordinates-of-clicks-with-glut-to-a-linked-list-in-c) about appending coordinates of clicks to a singly linked list, in order to loop through the linked list ,put vertices at the positions of the clicks and connect them [image: a linestrip with 6 vertices]

The answer given solved my issues with overflow of the linked list but afterwards i had problems with the display function, such that when i loop through the linked list and add those coordinates to `glVertex2i();`, it doesn't draw a linestrip when i click multiple times on the graphical window.

I tried to see what would happen when i removed the `while` loop, but that would cause segmentation fault.

These are the structs.

```
typedef struct vector{int x;int y;}Vector;
typedef struct VectorList{Vector X; struct VectorList*next; }node_v;
```

And i had declared these

```
Vector P;
node_v * prev;
```

And with the help of the answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527670/adding-coordinates-of-clicks-with-glut-to-a-linked-list-in-c), initialized `Vector P` with the coordinates of the clicks and appended to the linked list of vectors `node_v * prev;`

```
static void _display_CB()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,window_width,window_height,0,-1,1);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3ub(0,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    while(prev){
        glVertex2i( prev->X.x, prev->X.y);
        prev=prev->next;
    }

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

What changes should be done in `_display_CB()` for the program to be able to draw linestrips like in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prev` is the head of the list. You actually change the head of the list to the tail of the list when you do `elem = elem->next;`. Keep the head of the list and use a local variable `elem` to iterate through the list.
Furthermore the orthographic projection matrix `glOrtho` should be set to the current projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`):

```c
void _display_CB() {

    node_v * elem = prev;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, window_width, window_height, 0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    while(elem){
        glVertex2i(elem->X.x, elem->X.y);
        elem = elem->next;
    }
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```